# Visual Studio Installer Projects com PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, postgresql

Estou iniciando um projeto Windows Form C#, um aplicação comercial que o usuário baixa, instala e usa, sem complicações.
É possível configurar o Visual Studio Installer Projects para instalar junto o PostgreSQL sem que o usuário perceba, totalmente transparente?

Comment: Veja se não vale a pena fazer um projeto UWP, ao invés de WinForms.

Comment: Olá @ThiagoLunardi, obrigado pela dica. Tenho que garantir compatibilidade com pelo menos Windows XP. Motivo: muitos clientes com pequenos comércios que não desejam trocar seus hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode agrupar os binários do PostgreSQL em seu aplicativo, mas não incorporá-los no mesmo processo. Você precisará invocar initdb, pg_ctl, etc. em seu aplicativo e gerenciar a inicialização e o encerramento do postgres.

Funciona bem, mas não pode ser complicado.

Não use a porta padrão 5432 ou envie o instalador oficial do postgres e execute-o no modo silencioso. Isso confunde muito os usuários quando eles se perguntam de onde veio "postgres" e eles informaram sobre as listas de discussão sobre o nosso "adware" ou "instalação furtiva" ou o que quer que seja. Em vez disso, agrupe os binários do .zip, a árvore de instalação pré-compilada ou o que for. E não execute na porta 5432.

Lembre-se de incluir o tempo de execução do MSVC para os binários do postgres que você está usando, se eles precisam de um diferente para seu aplicativo.

Há muitos conselhos sobre como fazer isso com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Usando PowerShell a partir do VSI, é possível sim:

Instalação simples:

```
Import-Module Install-Postgres
Install-Postgres -User "postgres" -Password "ChangeMe!"
```

Com mais parametrizações:

```
Install-Postgres  
-User "postgres"  
-Password "ChangeMe!"  
-InstallUrl "http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-x64.exe"  
-InstallPath "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3"  
-DataPath "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data"  
-Locale "Romanian, Romania"  
-Port 5432  
-ServiceName "postgresql"
```

Fonte: http://blog.veritech.io/2014/10/postgresql-unattended-install.html